# How to call ArcGIS functionalities within a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis

I want to do somthing like this.Let's say I have a satellite image. I want to classify this into several vegetation indices. but I wantto do this programmatically. without involving any user or without opening ArcGIS. I know we can write script in python in arcgis to do some tasks. Like wise is there any way to call these ArcGIS functionalities within a normal .net application.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET (Windows Desktop) enables developers to create applications with high-quality interactive mapping, queries, geocoding, routing, data editing and advanced geographic analysis.

From here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/